# "Reduce-by-1"-isomorphic graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G, H$ be two finite, simple, undirected graphs. We call them "reduce-by-1"-isomorphic, or $r_1$-isomorphic for short, if there is a bijection $\psi: V(G) \to V(H)$ such that for all $v \in V(G)$ we have that $G \setminus \{v\}$ is isomorphic to $H \setminus \{\psi(v)\}$.

(Ulam's reconstruction conjecture, or some version of it, states that $r_1$-isomorphic implies isomorphic.)

Can we prove that if $G, H$ are $r_1$-isomorphic then they have the same chromatic number?

**EDIT**: Will ask about Hadwiger number in different post, it's better to ask one question per post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The chromatic polynomial, and therefore the chromatic number, was proved reconstructible by Tutte in his famous paper "All the king's horses".  I don't know about the Hadwiger number.

Comment: I am desperatly searching for a pdf of that article ( or alternatively that of the proceedings "Graph Theory and Related Topics" . Any idea ?

Comment: @JérômeJEAN-CHARLES You can read the conference proceedings [here](https://archive.org/details/graphtheoryrelat0000unse/page/n9/mode/2up) if you register for a free account. You can also write to me (my.name@anu.edu.au) for a copy of the original Waterloo technical report.

Comment: Ok thank you I mail you.